# Python - get midnight tomorrow night in timezone format

Tags: django

Im trying to get a list of all events occuring tomorrow from a django queryset. i assumed i needed tomorrow at midnight until tomorrow at 11:59pm. i think my tomorrow_end variable will be correct if tomorrow_start was set to 00:00:00 currently it gets the exact time now.

Can someone please tell me how to alter the time on the below to 00:00:00?

```
tomorrow_start = timezone.now() + timedelta(1)
tomorrow_end = tomorrow_start + timedelta(hours=11,minutes=59)
maintenance = CircuitMaintenance.objects.filter(start_time__gte=tomorrow_start, end_time__lte=tomorrow_end)
```

Answer (score 5):

Probably it doesn't look very elegant but you could use [datetime.combine](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.combine) to obtain tomorrow midnight:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, time 
tomorrow_start = datetime.combine(timezone.now().date(), time(0, 0)) + timedelta(1)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also do this:

```
import pytz
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
timezone = pytz.timezone('Europe/London')
dt_now = datetime.now(timezone)
tomorrow_start = datetime(dt_now.year, dt_now.month, dt_now.day, tzinfo=timezone) + timedelta(1)
tomorrow_end = tomorrow_start + timedelta(hours=12)
maintenance = CircuitMaintenance.objects.filter(start_time__gte=tomorrow_start, end_time__lt=tomorrow_end)
```

Note that we changed the query to get everything less than 12 hours from the start time.  This way you capture the 60 seconds from 11:59:00 to 12:00:00.

---

Sample output from ipython:

```
In [1]: import pytz
   ...: from datetime import datetime, timedelta
   ...: timezone = pytz.timezone('Europe/London')
   ...: dt_now = datetime.now(timezone)
   ...: tomorrow_start = datetime(dt_now.year, dt_now.month, dt_now.day, tzinfo=timezone) + timedelta(1)
   ...: tomorrow_end = tomorrow_start + timedelta(hours=12)
   ...:

In [2]: print timezone
Europe/London

In [3]: print dt_now
2017-01-17 19:42:23.044706+00:00

In [4]: print tomorrow_start
2017-01-18 00:00:00-00:01

In [5]: print tomorrow_end
2017-01-18 12:00:00-00:01
```

Comment: this is working but im getting a timezone warning again "RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField CircuitMaintenance.end_time received a naive datetime (2017-01-18 23:59:59) while time zone support is active.
  RuntimeWarning)"

Comment: Updated for timezone handling.

Comment: `timezone` was from your code up above.  If you don’t know what your timezone is, I can’t really help you.

Comment: i added: timezone = pytz.timezone('Europe/London')
dt_now = datetime.now(timezone) but still get the error...

Comment: I literally just pasted that code as the first line and it worked.